# How to run Laravel project without php artisan serve in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, localhost, laravel-artisan

I have updated the PHP version to 5.6.3 and create a project using laravel 5.3.0 . Now i want to run my project without php artisan serve. When i hit localhost , the index page is opened. But when i click one my project name it shows following error.
    ****The localhost page isn’t working****
Note that i have tried following method to get rid of this issue.
    1. copy .htaccess file from public directory to project folder
    2. rename the server.php to index.php 
But it is not working. Any ideas in this regard?

Comment: You can create a virtual host for serving your laravel application. read: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Comment: Have you tried navigating to your project directory's public folder instead? All laravel files are served through the public directory.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: @aynber i have tried this method but error is still there

Comment: @gorans93 i have Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Comment: Do you have  permissions to read/write/execute files from Laravel directory?

Comment: No i have not can you have idea of a  useful resource about permissions like
mod_rewrite 
, Alloworide all
i will be very helpful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using LAMP and you want to run Laravel project without Artisan, you have to navigate from browser to `/laravel/public` directory. Follow laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick

But if you getting errors like 500 and your page don't work, possibly you have to change permissions of your Laravel project directory.

Try `sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/your/laravel/project` 
or  `sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/your/laravel/project`
for more refer with this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: thanks . it helped me to sort out my error. I have given the permission to my project. Although my certain java scripts and bootstrap files were not working. But as i gave permission to them using                                           sudo chmod -R 770 /path/to/your/laravel/project 
They started working 
I came to know that my AllowOverride was none i changed it to AllowOverride All in apache/config.php file.